# Print without unicode symbol, but keep as unicode

Tags: python, unicode, python-unicode

I need to print values that have non ascii symbols. These values are unicode strings. So I have this list:

```
some_list = [u'Data', u'Svoris', u'Perdavimo laikas', 
    u'\u012evykio vietos adresas', u'Kvietimo prie\u017eastis']
```

I can print it with with non ascii symbols, but `u` is still kept:

```
print 'hello %s' % (str(some_list)[1:-1].decode('unicode-escape'))

hello u'Data', u'Svoris', u'Perdavimo laikas', u'Įvykio vietos adresas', u'Kvietimo priežastis'
```

How can I hide `u` too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're printing the `str` of a `list`, and slicing off the `[]` brackets. Instead, `join` the strings together:

```
some_list = [u'Data', u'Svoris', u'Perdavimo laikas', 
    u'\u012evykio vietos adresas', u'Kvietimo prie\u017eastis']

print 'hello %s' % ', '.join(some_list)
```

Outputs:

```
hello Data, Svoris, Perdavimo laikas, Įvykio vietos adresas, Kvietimo priežastis
```

This also removes the `'` quotes.

Comment: Thanks. Much better solution.